# Chrome Devtools Not Showing @ Symbol For Cookies

Tags: reactjs, npm, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, session-cookies

So I'm working with react cookies, when a user signs in I want to save that information in cookies.

This is the code I'm using in my front end, everything is working when I access Chrome Dev tools > Applications > Cookies.

And even in the console the correct email shows

However in the cookies tab say for example the email input by the user is 
sometestemail@gmail.com it translates it too -->  sometestemail#40gmail.com

basically replacing the @ with #40, I'm not sure whats wrong as I'm printing the email user passed to the console and it shows the proper sometestemail@gmail.com

Any Ideas?

```
const cookies = new Cookies();

    cookies.set('userEmail', this.state.email, { path: '/sign-up' });
    cookies.set('userPassword', this.state.password, {path: '/sign-up'});
    const email= cookies.get('userEmail');
    console.log(email); // Pacman
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to URI character encoding.

You can read about encoding/decoding special characters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)